# C# problem using StreamWriter to text file

Tags: c#, file, text-files, large-files, streamwriter

I'm trying to write the numbers 0-28,110,000 to a text file with 0's padding the smaller numbers (believe it or not, this is NOT a homework assignment).

```
Desired Output  
00000001  
00000002  
00000003  
...  
28109999  
28110000
```

But when I write this to a text file, the output looks like:

```
  00000001  
  00000002  
  00000003  
  ...  
  27145011  
  27
```

With the last number stopping in the middle.
Can anyone see why this is happening and how I can correct it?

Full code

```
  long lastCode = 28110000;
        int padSize = (lastCode == 0) ? 1 : (int)Math.Log10(lastCode) + 1;

        String filename = @"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\" + lastCode + "_sequentialCodes.txt";
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false, Encoding.ASCII);
        writer.AutoFlush = true;

        for (int i = 1; i < lastCode + 1; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(i.ToString().PadLeft(padSize, '0'));

            if (i % 100 == 0)
            {
                Console.Write(".");
            }
        }

        writer.Close();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(lastCode + " codes written to \n" + filename);
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: To me the output looks like the writer wasn't closed or flushed, although I clearly see your code does this.

Comment: There is no reader in the code.  This is a writing operation.

Comment: Are you looking at the file too soon, before the Close() statement executes?  Use the *using* statement to avoid trouble with exceptions.

Comment: @Hans Passant- No, I'm not opening the file until well after the close().  How would I use using in this code?  Also, your comment should probably be another possible answer.

Comment: As a debugging step, try running the program with `for (int i = 1001; i < lastCode + 1; i++)` and see if it stops exactly 1000 steps further into your loop.  I'm not aware of limitations on the stream writer, but that could be your issue.

Comment: Also move `i` outside the for construct and print it's value to the console after the loop.

Comment: @MAW74656 Have you tried keeping AutoFlush off and explicitly calling Flush at the end prior to the Close?

Comment: For interest sake, what is the size of the resulting file? It should be around 280MB, are you sure your text viewer can handle that?

Comment: @leppie- I'm using Notepad++.

Comment: @MAW74656: You might be close to the limits of it, not sure, never used it, but own editor started flaking around 600k lines (GDI+ limitation (lines * line height must be less than 24bits)).

Comment: Can you recommend a text viewer for really large files?

Comment: @MAW74656 You're using Notepad++ - that's fine.

Comment: @MAW74656: I use Total Commander's viewer (http://www.ghisler.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled with VS2008, opened output text with Notepad++ 5.7.  All 28110000 points printed in the console, and in the output file.  You're code is correct, so the problem must lie elsewhere.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long lastCode = 28110000;
            int padSize = (lastCode == 0) ? 1 : (int)Math.Log10(lastCode) + 1;

            String filename = @"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\" + lastCode + "_sequentialCodes.txt";
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false, Encoding.ASCII);
            writer.AutoFlush = true;

            for (int i = 1; i < lastCode + 1; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(i.ToString().PadLeft(padSize, '0'));

                if (i % 100 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
                }
            }

            writer.Close();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(lastCode + " codes written to \n" + filename);
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Not exactly the news you want to hear, but it should help you find what's wrong with your system/setup.  32bit core 2 duo, Windows XP SP3

Comment: What was the output?  Your system specs sound like mine.

Comment: Output is a 270+MB text file, with the numbers printed on one line a pop.

Comment: Your output is what I want/expect.

Comment: Try creating a fresh project, copy/paste the above code, and see what you come up with.

Comment: @Caladin- I appreciate the screenshot, but I believed what you said :-)

Comment: What size file does your run output?

Comment: What version of notepad ++ are you running?  I'd update to 5.8 and see if it still doesn't show everything...it looks like the data's there.

Comment: @Caladin- That was it.  I was on 5.6.2 and updated to the latest version and its all there.  Geez, my first issue with Notepad++ ever.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to replace `writer.Close()` by `writer.Dispose()` ?

I solved my similar problem by this way.

Comment: -I've solved by other means, but isn't it best practice to not user .Dispose() directly and rather use using blocks (which I didn't use here) or to let the Garbage Collector do its job?

Comment: @MAW74656 `using` blocks are the preferred way to go as `.Dispose()` is guaranteed to be called in the event of an exception being thrown as it ends up as a try/finally. You should note that the Garbage Collector won't call `.Dispose()`. It will call a finaliser if the class defines one (which should call `.Dispose()`) but an `IDisposable` doesn't have to have a finaliser.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, because I've just run Your code and It worked without any problem. Last number is exactly 28110000. One thing I changed was commenting the i % 100 == 0 loop.

Comment: @zavaz- That is really weird.  The only effect commenting out that loop will have is less console output (and thus much faster operation).  Right?

Comment: i'm verifying.  I added a print statement of what i's current value is..it makes it slow, but i should be finishing in a few minutes.

Comment: @MAW74656: Yes, maybe your text viewer is weak?

Comment: Yep. Without this loop it should be faster and that's all. It shouldn't have any other effects.

Comment: @leppie- Notepad++ isn't enough for this?

Comment: I'm using Notepad++ so it's not the text viewer  problem

Comment: I've always had great experience with Notepad++.  Have it installed on all of my systems.

Comment: Ran your code, as is, opened with notepad++, see all 28110000 entries.

Comment: Just ran the code and opened on Notepad++ 5.8 and it did indeed display the last line appropriately 28110000

Answer (score -2):

To me the output looks like the reader wasn't closed or flushed, although I clearly see your code does this.

Maybe `Math.Log10` returns a wrong value for too large values. Did you try a fixed padding size?

If an exception occures, the writer isn't closed in your app. Usw the using statement for that:

```
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, false, Encoding.ASCII))
   {
       // do your stuff here
   }
```

Comment: Math.Log10 works correctly based on previous testing.  Also, although it may be better (different?) code, shouldn't using work the same as my method if both are coded right?

Comment: using takes care of closing the underlying stream should an exception occur and since your code is not wrapped in a  try/finally you could in theory leave the stream open

Comment: @Aaron- Yes, I'm aware of the theoretical problem, but the code clearly closes the stream, so this is not a concern here.

Comment: @MAW74656 If writer.WriteLine(i.ToString().PadLeft(padSize, '0')); fails with an exception it will not close the stream

Comment: @MAW74656 Yes; the using reference I don't believe has anything to do with your issue; just a best practices approach

Comment: @Aaron- Got it.  Is that generally excepted best practice?  Or programmer preference?  Also, is there a performance difference?

Comment: @MAW74656 Yes it is best practice; using makes use of  IDisposable.Dispose so the object implementing using must implement that interface; performance should be a non-issue